# Path security and before_filters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently creating an app where users can create and apply for jobs. However as I am fairly new to rails I am facing a fairly significant security feature in that if any user knows the correct path, for example:

```
 localhost:3000/users/user_id/apps
```

Then they can see any application made by any user for any job!

I am fairly sure that I need to use a `before_filter` to check that the current_user.id matches either the user_id found in my jobs table for each job or matches the user_id found in my applications table.

I am really not sure how to structure this though or where to apply the filter - for example is it better to create the filter in the application controller and then apply a `skip_before_filter` instance where needed.

Any help people can offer on contructing this code and where to place it would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start looking at authorization solutions such as cancan, a simple approach is to avoid doing

```
App.find params[:id]
```

Since an app is associated to a user and you've got current_user setup you can do

```
app = current_user.apps.find params[:id]
```

Which will only find apps associated with the user, no matter what the parameters to find.

Where cancan really comes into its own is when you need a more complicated who can do what system. For example a user might be able to  edit any job they've created but view (and not edit) another set of jobs.

For example

```
can :manage, Project, :user.id  => user.id
can :read, Project, :department => user.department
```

This would allow users full access to any of their projects and read access to projects in their department

Another thing about cancan is that rather than having before_filters or macros scattered around your controllers you declare the rules in one place, so it's usually easier to see what's going on. There's loads more info on the cancan wiki an a railscast too.

Answer (score 0):

You are right a `before_filter` might be an sollution but its not the state of the art solution. Theres a railscast for that,...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan/

When your using cancan but not devise you need to create the `current_user` helper that should return the User object of the currently logged in user...